# Is there any tools for VSTO add-in automatic build besides visual studio team services?

Tags: ms-office, vsto, office-addins

Hi guys just as title says, my question is is there any other tools besides Visual studio team services, that aim more specifically at VSTO-Addin build process? I am trying to automated the build process but Visual studio team services do not have all the options i want.

Answer (score 0):

Try CMAKE, but no magic you will need the MS build tools underneath. Basically CMAKE will do what VS does. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks will have a look